# Как собрать стороннюю библиотеку с открытым кодом в VS? C++

Tags: c++, build

Допустим я клонировал/скачал с гитхаба проект с открытым исходным кодом. Как мне собрать этот проект из .h и .cpp в .lib формат, используя VS? Где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: а в проекте уже есть файл какой то билд системы - студийный солюшн, cmake, ,make  или что то подобное? а ещё почитать документацию. Но вполне может быть, что собрать не получится - код может быть написан под линукс/мак специфичное

Comment: Ну допустим я сам написал код. Есть набор .h и .cpp файлов. Можно где-то почитать, как из этого собрать библиотеку и потом использовать в своих проектах?

Comment: Отсюда можно начать: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160